# HTTP credentials - why convert to bytes then string?

Tags: c#, http

I've seen many examples for including credentials in an HTTP header, they all look something along the lines of:

```
string _auth = string.Format("{0}:{1}", "myUser","myPwd");
string _enc = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_auth));
string _cred = string.Format("{0} {1}", "Basic", _enc);
req.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = _cred;
```

The credentials string is converted to a byte array, and then back to a string.

Why is this done? What's to stop you just sending the original credentials string? (assuming SSL is set up to encrypt this)

Comment: The original string is not Base64. And `Convert.ToBase64String` operates on a `byte[]` - that's why you have to call `GetBytes` first.

Comment: I believe that one reason is that your string may contain chars that do not transmit well over http. Converting to Base64, I believe, ensures a char set that will be transmitted. I'm not sure enough about this to make it an answer though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not simply converting a string to bytes and then back. In fact, you start with a regular string and end up with a base64 encoded string. The code is actually needed because it converts your original auth string into a format that the HTTP server expects.

To understand this, let's step through your code:

```
string _auth = string.Format("{0}:{1}", "myUser","myPwd");
```

This takes your username and password and concatenates them to create a string of the format **myUser:myPwd**

```
string _enc = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_auth));
```

This line can be split into two parts. Inside the first set of parentheses, `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes` converts *myUser:myPwd* into a byte array (more specifically, 109, 121, 85, 115, 101, 114, 58, 109, 121, 80, 119, 100).

Then, `Convert.ToBase64String` takes those bytes and converts them to a string that looks like this: **bXlVc2VyOm15UHdk**

And this is a classic [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)-encoded string that your HTTP server expects. Finally, the third line prepares a header entry of the format "Basic bXlVc2VyOm15UHdk", which complies with the HTTP specification for the *Authorization* field.

You can learn more about this kind of authorization on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication#Client_side).

Comment: So it's to achieve a format which is standard protocol for HTTP? Great thanks.

Comment: @FBryant87 Pretty much. Although [RFC 1945](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1945#section-11) doesn't actually give any reasons as to _why_ it's base64 encoded, so my best guess is that it has something to do with encoding special characters.

Comment: I think the idea was that it could be extended relatively easily to a system using binary data, such in a scheme using a cryptographic-hash, though since such a scheme would by definition not be Basic Authentication any more, that wasn't really necessary.